# Can I simplify this use of RTTI in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

I'm doing some work with RTTI in Delphi XE3 and so far, this has resulted in a call to a procedure as follows:

```
procedure MyProc( ARecordInstance : pointer; ARecordType : PTypeInfo );
```

and I call this routine as follows:

```
MyProc( @MyRec TypeInfo( TMyRec ));
```

This all works fine.

It occurs to me that I might be able to simplify my procedure to:

```
procedure MyProc( var ARecord ); or procedure MyProc( ARecord : pointer );
```

..if I can get the type info from ARecord within my procedure. Working with an 'instance' such as 'ARecord' though, TypeInfo gives 'expects a type identifier' error, which is fair. Is there any way that I can pass a single pointer reference to my record and then extract the type from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to support multiple types, you can wrap your procedure inside of a class that has a Generic parameter, then the procedure will know what data type it is working with, eg:

```
type
  MyClass<T> = class
  public
    class procedure MyProc(var AInstance : T);
  end;

class procedure MyClass<T>.MyProc(var AInstance : T);
var
  InstanceType: PTypeInfo;
begin
  InstanceType := TypeInfo(T);
  //...
end;
```

.

```
MyClass<TMyRec>.MyProc(MyRec);
```

Comment: +1 This is the only way I also found out. But no big benefit between `MyClass<TMyRec>.MyProc(MyRec)` and `MyProc(MyRec,TypeInfo(TMyRec))`... and the generic version will generate more code, and is subject to the Delphi compiler unstabilities about generics. But you will get strong typing check, which may be worth it.

Comment: Welcome to Delphi shortcomings. Had this been a C++ question instead, the compiler can automatically work out the value of `T` without needing it to be expressed explicitally, and `MyProc` does not need to be wrapped in a class in order to write generic code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just code, with an un-typed var parameter:

```
procedure MyProc(var ARecordInstance; ARecordType : PTypeInfo);
begin
  ...
```

You will be able to call:

```
MyProc(MyRec,TypeInfo(TMyRec));
```

So avoid to type `@MyRec`. But you will also do not have strong type checking.

Using generics as proposed by Remy will allow strong typing, but will generate a bit more code.

Comment: The point of the question is that he does not want to have to specify `TypeInfo(TMyRec)` as an explicit parameter, he wants the code to figure it out automatically based on what type of record is passed to the `ARecordInstance` parameter.